# I want to install semPlot packages in R

Tags: r, stringi, semplot

if i do install.packages("semPlot") in R,

"C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu69/ -Iicu69/unicode -Iicu69/common -Iicu69/i18n -DU_STRINGI_PATCHES -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0601 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c stri_exception.cpp -o stri_exception.o

is repeating because of the stringi packages in semPlot packages.
how can i solve this problem?

Comment: What error did you get? When R asks if you want to compile package from source, just select NO to use the binary file

Comment: I apologize if this is a stupid question, but are you certain that *that* line is repeating over and over? The `stringi` package has quite a few files to compile, and most of that line will be the same for each of them (varying only in the last two arguments, e.g., `stri_exception.cpp` and its `.o`). If it really is just this one file compiling over and over, then that is likely a question on `Make`, not R, since ... "make" should definitely not be doing that.